# MySQL v5.7.4 - Is there no longer a way to remove duplicates with "unique index"?

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

So apparently after mySQL v5.7.4, the keyword `IGNORE` is no longer supported, which nukes this useful duplicate-removing query:

```
alter IGNORE table labs 
add unique index noDUPES (ruid, test_sname, test_value, units, ref_range, entry_date);
```

Everywhere I've looked notes the discontinued support of `IGNORE`, but doesn't suggest a replacement.

Is there still a simple way to utilize the power of `UNIQUE INDEX` to remove duplicates without using `IGNORE` after mySQL v5.7.4?

Answer (score 1):

Many people consider it a good thing that creating an index does not delete records from the underlying table.  One method is to use a temporary table, truncate, and insert:

```
create temporary table tokeep as
     select distinct ruid, test_sname, test_value, units, ref_range, entry_date
     from labs;

truncate table labs;

insert into labs(ruid, test_sname, test_value, units, ref_range, entry_date)
    select ruid, test_sname, test_value, units, ref_range, entry_date
    from tokeep;
```

Note:  This version assumes that these are the only columns in the table.  If there are other columns, similar logic will work.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Are you saying that there is no longer any way to make `UNIQUE INDEX` enforce itself when you add it to a table?

Comment: @Dylan . . . I think that "functionality" was removed.  It is very dangerous.